# Package reference to local when not in release mode

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nuget, nuget-package

I have a solution `W92.Externals` with 3 projects inside:

- `W92.Externals.Domain` (netstandard 2.0)
- `W92.Externals.FunctionApps` (netstandard 2.0)
- `W92.Externals.FunctionApps.Servicebus` (netstandard 2.0)

Each of the projects is deployed to NuGet and is used by many other microservices/projects via NuGet.

Now in the solution `W92.Externals` I decided to use internal dependencies, meaning `W92.Externals.FunctionApps` will have dependency to `W92.Externals.Domain`.

The `W92.Externals.FunctionApp.csproj` looks like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="W92.Externals.Domain" Version="2019.7.16.139486" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="3.3.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.3" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="2.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.26" />
<PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
```

Now my goal is to:

1.When I work on my local - take dependencies from `W92.Externals.Domain` as project dependency, something like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Common\src\W92.Externals\W92.Externals.Domain.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2.When changes are deployed (in release mode) the package should be taken from nuget..as it has been shown above:

```
<PackageReference Include="W92.Externals.Domain" Version="2019.7.16.139486" />
```

Is it possible somehow to achieve?

In root folder, I have **nuget.config** file. Maybe somehow can I use it to solve the problem?

I have a project in VS 2017. Version 15.9.12
The projects are in "Microsoft.NET.Sdk".

Comment: Maybe try [msbuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the normal `ItemGroup` to define the package references to normal third-party nuget packages:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus" Version="3.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.ServiceBus" Version="3.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="2.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="1.0.26" />
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Then use [msbuild conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-conditions?view=vs-2019) in xx.csproj file to manage the dependency to your own `W92.Externals.Domain`:

```
  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'">
    <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Common\src\W92.Externals\W92.Externals.Domain.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Release'">
    <PackageReference Include="W92.Externals.Domain" Version="2019.7.16.139486" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

In this way, I suggest you reload the project every time after you `switch between the Debug and Release mode` to refresh the UI in solution explorer and avoid mess up the setting.

When you start VS to open this solution, it will read the content of project file and load corresponding references for you.

For example, if you open the solution in `debug mode` by default, then it will use project reference instead of package reference. It's what you want, but when you switch to `release mode`, you need to `unload the project and reload it in solution explorer` to load settings for release mode.

Comment: Glad that it makes some help :)